# Dismiss view controller when navigating

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an IOS Application in swift and I found a pretty big problem in my case.

If I would do this in Android I would use fragments and just replace the current fragment to a new one, but nothing seem to be equal to fragment in swift, so.

I start on view controller A and then I'm navigating to view controller B (The user should just pick their name in this view) and from B I want to navigate to C. But when I navigate to C I need view controller B to be dismissed to avoid the stacking. But I can't find a good way to just remove the current view controller and navigate to a new one.

```
    func navigateToService(selectedCar: String!){

    if let storyboard = storyboard{
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BookServiceViewController") as! BookServiceViewController

        self.dismiss(animated: true) //<---

        vc.selectedCar = selectedCar

        self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I've tried this and a lot more so far. But nothing seem to work in my case. The code I've added in the thread is just closing the view immediately and is not opening a new one.

So how can I navigate from A -> B -> Dimiss B -> C?

### TEMPORARY EDIT, WILL BE REMOVED

```
    func navigateToService(selectedCar: String!){

    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        if let storyboard = self.storyboard{
           let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BookServiceViewController") as! BookServiceViewController


           vc.selectedCar = selectedCar

           self.present(vc, animated: true)
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: if you want to go back from C to A, you can use unwindSegue via storyboard, or popToViewController(viewControllerA). There is no need to dismiss B

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik The reason why I want to dismiss B is because I'm using "automatic" and when I drag view controller C (to make it dismiss) the view controller B is still there. 

So I've to dismiss both C and B when dragging down to dismiss

Comment: Have you tried `self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: { self.dismiss(animated: true) })`?

Comment: in this case you must pass selected item from B to A, dismiss B in completionBlock, call C

Comment: you can try to add your first vc as a subview and then remove it from parent and set your next view

Comment: This could probably help you [Dismiss view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668818/how-to-dismiss-viewcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik what do you mean with selected item? The name in vc B?

Comment: @Was'SiimBenHssen Subview is like a container? or what is a subview in this case?

Comment: @ZakariaBenHmida I will check it out, hold on

Comment: @Putte yes its like a container check this maybe it will helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932428/loading-a-view-controller-inside-a-view-in-xcode

Comment: @Putte yes, I mean your variable you want to pass to C

Answer (score 0):

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
   # do your job in here
}
```

present your `UIViewController` in here but you have to get an instance of the `UIViewController` which will be presented.

## Edit

Describe a protocol

```
protocol Handler{
    func  handleIt()
}


class AController: UIViewController, Handler {

    func handleIt() {
        // present controller C
        /*
         self.present( C Controller )
         */
    }
...

    func presentFunction(){

        var controller = BController()
        controller.delegate = self

    }

}
```

`Conformance` it with this protocol then set it with the `present C controller`.

```
class BController: UIViewController{

    var delegate: Handler?

    func dismissFunction(){

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        delegate?.handleIt()

    }
    ...
}
```

In controller B you have to describe like this. So when you trigger dismiss function call the `delegate's` `handleIt` function. It `presents` `C` from `A`.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Check my temporary edit, please. :) Thats how you mean?

Comment: yeah, can you try it basically?

Comment: I tried. But it closes both view controller B & C :/

Comment: Actually the working scheme is true because you are present B from A, your base `UIViewController` is `A`.

Comment: True.

My base vc is A (also the root), and then I want to temporary show vc B (just to pick the correct name) and once I press navigate to C, I would like to get vc B to disappear.

I hope you understand, I don't know how to explain it good enough.

Comment: I edited it to work as you wish. You better use protocol based solution.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. Where should I add all this? Haha

Comment: I'll try and see what I can do.

But doesn't this seem to be a very "hard" way of doing this? I mean, why don't they just have an easy shit like "dismiss(animated: false){ self.present(vc, animated: true)}"

Comment: Because you'll call dismiss function in B, so that means B will die. Then you try to present C from not A but B so dead one :)

Comment: Makes a bit sense hehe. 

But, inside your "handle" it function, you have commented out code. Should I leave it like that? or should I add code for navigating to C?

Comment: you have to code for self.present( CViewController )

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

First, your current presented view(B) make push view with this code and after try to present your 'BookServiceViewController' view(C)

```
    let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your_Current_Presented_View") as! Your_Current_Presented_View

    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextVC)
    nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And after present, Call your function

```
func navigateToService(selectedCar: String!){

if let storyboard = storyboard{
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BookServiceViewController") as! BookServiceViewController

    self.dismiss(animated: true) //<---

    vc.selectedCar = selectedCar

    self.present(vc, animated: true)
}}
```

Comment: It's closing both B and C :/

Comment: @Putte I edit my answer because it not works. try my new code please, i'm edit now. remind it's all change.

Comment: I edit my answer, if not understand tell me your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In A:

```
func goToB(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "B_ViewController") as? B_ViewController else{return}
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func proceedToC(selectedCar:String){
        guard let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "C_ViewController") as? C_ViewController else{return}
        controller.car = selectedCar
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In B:

```
func goToC(_ sender: Any) {
        if let presenter = self.presentingViewController, presenter.isKind(of: A_ViewController.self), let vc = presenter as? A_ViewController{
            self.dismiss(animated: false) {
                vc.proceedToC(selectedCar: "Corvette")
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is one way to do it. However, I'd suggest using @elia's way as it is more elegant approach

Comment: I did try, but didn't work really.

I changed a bit on the application and I'm running this is another way atm. But I'll see if I will give it another try soon. :) Thanks

Comment: @Putte I tried the same on a demo and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

1.when you are navigating to B just pass the A controller object like this:-
  @IBAction func GoToB(_ sender: Any) {
        let Bcontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "B") as! B
        Bcontroller.Aobje = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Bcontroller, animated: true)
    }

2.the time of navigation from B to C use A controller object for navigation like given below.

```
var Aobje = A()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func BtoC(_ sender: Any) {
    let Ccontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "C") as! C
         Aobje.navigationController?.pushViewController(Ccontroller, animated: true)
    self.removeFromParent()
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? :)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean

Comment: 1. create a A controller type object in B controller.

Comment: Like how can I do that? :o

Comment: i have changed the  post with the code   so use it.

Answer (score 0):

## Multiple dismissal at same time

You should dismiss the controller who presents this one to dismiss both together in this case:

```
self.presentingViewController!.dismiss(animated: true) // `!` is to makeing sure it's not crashing.
```

---

#### Demo:

Use this simple code to demo:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func present() {
        let destination = storyboard!.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        if presentingViewController != nil {
            // You are not in the A
            if presentingViewController?.presentingViewController != nil {
                // You are in the C
                presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
                return
            } else {
                // You are in the B
                destination.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
            }
        }
        present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

1. Create a single view application
2. Drag a button into the view controller
3. Replace the `ViewController` class with the provided code
4. Connect the `@IBAction`
5. Run it to see the result.

---

## Change the root of the window entirely:

If you want to get rid of the entire stack and act like you just start the app starting from the `C` view controller, you can just **set the root of the window** to `C`.

```
view.window!.rootViewController = destination
```

This is like you set the initialViewController arrow on the destination at first place.